# JSF creates a new SessionScoped Bean for every request

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My problem is that one : at every http request, a new session scoped bean is created and I don't know why.

Here is my jsf index page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/default.css"/>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <p:growl autoUpdate="true" showDetail="true" globalOnly="true"/>

    <h:form id="f_main">

        <ui:include src="#{pageBean.page}.xhtml"/>

    </h:form>

</h:body>
</html>
```

Here is my PageBean

```
package web.bean.system;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import web.bean.AbstractBean;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class PageBean extends AbstractBean {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -882977117976414497L;
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(PageBean.class);
    public static final String HOME = "home";
    private static int IT = 0;

    private String page;

    public PageBean() {
        LOG.debug(IT++);
        this.page = HOME;
    }

    public String getPage() {
        LOG.debug(page);
        return this.page;
    }

    public void setPage(String page) {
        LOG.debug(page);
        this.page = page;
    }
}
```

In this case, the home page is empty.

But when I take a look at the logs after refreshing a lot of time, I can see that a new bean is created for every http request.

I have verified that I realy use javax.faces.bean and not an other package but I don't know why It doesn't work...

Have you any solution for me ?

Comment: Try moving the code from the constructor into an `init` method, annotated with `@PostConstruct`. Does it make any difference?

Comment: Initially I had done like this but it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

That may happen if the HTTP session is not properly maintained between the client and the server. Before all, first learn how HTTP sessions work by carefully reading the "HttpSession" section of this answer: [How do servlets work? Instantiation, sessions, shared variables and multithreading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/how-do-servlets-work-instantiation-session-variables-and-multithreading/3106909#3106909).

Now, you should understand that they're by default backed by cookies. You should now also understand that if cookies are not maintained by the client or instantly destroyed by the server for some reason, then the session won't be maintained across requests.

If you're using a bit modern webbrowser with builtin web developer toolset, press F12 to show it up and open the "Net"/"Network" tab. Look in the response header for `Set-Cookie` and in subsequent request header for `Cookie`. If `Cookie` is absent in request header and thus the server returns a new `Set-Cookie` header on the response, then it means that the client does not support cookies. Or if the right `Cookie` header is present and the server still returns a new `Set-Cookie` header on every response, then it means that the server's code has somewhere a line which calls `HttpSession#invalidate()` on every request (perhaps a homegrown authentication filter which is written by a starter).

Comment: So, the HTTP session is properly maintained? In other words, `HttpSession#getId()` returns the same value everytime across the requests on the same browser session?