# SessionScoped Beans created multiple times for same request on (fast) double click

Tags: jsf, cdi, jsf-2.2, session-scope

environment:

omnifaces 2.6

mojarra 2.2.12

weld-servlet-2.2.9

tomcat 8

and a minimal bean-setup:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.enterprise.context.SessionScoped;
import javax.inject.Named;

@Named("test")
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -2697121845047289456L;


   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
     System.out.println("TestBean.init()");     
   }
}
```

test.xhtml

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">        

    #{test}

</ui:composition>
```

after tomcat is started, requesting quickly many times page **test.xhtml** (GET) results in the following console-output:

```
TestBean.init()
TestBean.init()
TestBean.init()
TestBean.init()
```

the same behaviour occurs when replacing cdi with jsf-annotations:

```
@ManagedBean(name="test")
@javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {
}
```

any ideas what this is caused by how to fix that?

**Update:**
i just reproduced this behaviour with a brand new project to ensure that there is nothing polluted in my code or configuration. only included latest mojarra 2.2.14 and tomcat 8.0.36. drag the link

```
localhost:8080/SessionBeanTest/test
```

to browser bar and started fast clicking on this link while tomcat starts. you'll see the same outputs. **how can i prevent the creation of multiple sessions for the same request?**

```
package test;

import javax.servlet.annotation.WebListener;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionEvent;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener;

@WebListener
public class SessionCounter implements HttpSessionListener {

    private static int count;

   @Override
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("session created: " + event.getSession().getId());
        count++;
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("session destroyed: " + event.getSession().getId());
        count--;
    }

    public static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
}
```

web.xml

```
 <listener><listener-class>test.SessionCounter</listener-class>
```

```
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

@ManagedBean(name="test")
@SessionScoped
public class TestBean implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

   @PostConstruct
   public void init(){
     HttpServletRequest request =  (HttpServletRequest)FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequest();
      System.out.println("TestBean.init() with requested session-id: " + request.getRequestedSessionId());
   }

   public Integer getTotalSessions(){
     return SessionCounter.getCount();
   }
}
```

test.xhtml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"      
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html">

<h:head>
    <title>SessionBean-Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>    
    <h2>#{test.totalSessions}</h2>
</h:body>
```

output for clicking fast 4 times:

```
session created: 85473180423E40234184E2B748A3BF65
session created: 984C12EAF08B8A427C23B8CA98C6EF10
session created: DA147A440A9D03860B110E8AD063B548
session created: 577261D977E090D3E67E35DB55A97CD5
TestBean.init() with requested session-id: D385B49654C289FE41E718BE3BC9F5FA
TestBean.init() with requested session-id: D385B49654C289FE41E718BE3BC9F5FA
TestBean.init() with requested session-id: D385B49654C289FE41E718BE3BC9F5FA
TestBean.init() with requested session-id: D385B49654C289FE41E718BE3BC9F5FA
```

Comment: Is this helpful? http://stackoverflow.com/q/18041180

Comment: sadly not. i also removed all filters to track down the problem, but one session-cookie with same sessionid is present. problem occurs with all major browsers. one important thing i've forgot to mention: this only happens with first series of clicks during/after server start. then the bean gets constructed as many times i click - from that point, everything goes as it should: sessionbeans aren't recreated while request/viewscope-beans get recreated once when i perform a new GET.

Comment: @Steve Did you ever solve this? I'm seeing the same thing

Comment: i am sorry. wasn't able to solve this and lose sight of it.

Comment: may this be helpful http://palkonyves.blogspot.com/2012/12/ive-been-using-postconstruct-wrong-way.html ?